# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am working on a project migrated from WLS8 to WildFly 10. Hibernate 3.3 (implementation of JPA) was used in WLS8. However, WildFly 10 doesn't support this version so I use the default Hibernate (version 5) bundled with WildFly 10.

But I got run time error:

> ERROR [stderr] (default task-32) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: com.x.switch.entity.LOC

Here is the file/class structure in `.war`:

> --WEB-INF
>    --classes
>      --com
>       --META-INF
>         --persistence.xml
>     --lib
>    --web.xml
>     --jboss-web.xml

I couldn't figure out why the entity is not found (as it is under classes and packaged in war file).

Comment: Do you use annotations or configure your entities inside persistence.xml?

Comment: Annotations are used in java code.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically after I list all Entities in persistence.xml, the error is gone. It's fixed but I still don't understand why I need to do so since every Entity is annotated.